# Dropdown default selected value not working with angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following select list:

```
<select ng-change="LoadCarType()" ng-model="rowsPerPage">
            <option selected="selected">5</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
</select>
```

In this case defult selection is not working.If I inspect the element I find the following output:

```
        <select ng-change="LoadCarType()" ng-model="rowsPerPage" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
            <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
```

If I remove the part:

```
ng-change="LoadCarType()" ng-model="rowsPerPage"
```

then everything is ok.

Comment: Could you include your controller where LoadCarType() and rowsPerPage are defined?

Comment: try to set your rowsPerPage variable to one of the options, don't let it be null or undefined

Comment: don't use `selected` attribute..instead try `ng-init="rowsPerPage=5"` in your html..

Comment: and since all the options (5 10 50 100) are strings so set your rowsPerPage = '5'; to select first option

Comment: set the value ahead of time as suggested. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9g67b1d/5/